# Symbolic solution of irrational equation

Tags: equation-solving

Is there any a nice looking solution to the following equation?

```
eq[x_] := 2 x q1 - 2 q2/x^3 - (4 x^3 q3 - 4 q5/x^5)/(4 Sqrt[x^4 q3 + q4 + q5/x^4])
```

Better than the one *Mathematica* gives as output?

```
 Solve[ eq[x] == 0, x]
```

Comment: If you simplify it to the form of polynomial, you will find that it has degree 16. Since there is no formula for the solution of polynomial with degree bigger than 4, I think there is no nice look solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can ask **what is a nice solution**, should it be **as simple as possible**? Isn't it a bit vague concept?

Whatever that means there is a plenty of simple (and nice) solutions, e.g. simply `x == 1` for all parameters equal to `1`:

```
eq[1] /. {q1 -> 1, q2 -> 1, q3 -> 1, q4 -> 1, q5 -> 1}
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

Here we can provide appropriate conditions for parameters ensuring that `x == 1` is a solution:

```
Solve[ eq[1] == 0 && (q1 | q2 | q3 | q4 | q5)  ∈  Reals, {q1}]
```

> ```
> {{q1 -> 
>   ConditionalExpression[ q2 - 1/2 Sqrt[(q3^2 - 2 q3 q5 + q5^2)/(q3 + q4 + q5)],
>                          (q2 | q5) ∈ Reals && q3 - q5 <= 0 && q3 + q4 + q5 > 0]},
>  {q1 -> 
>   ConditionalExpression[ q2 + 1/2 Sqrt[(q3^2 - 2 q3 q5 + q5^2)/(q3 + q4 + q5)],
>                          (q2 | q5) ∈ Reals && q3 - q5 > 0 && q3 + q4 + q5 > 0]}}
> ```

So I have answered the question (as it is).

**Edit**

Similarily we can find many solutions using `FindInstance` with some conditions restricting the solution space like e.g. searching for integer solutions, here we want to find $5$ of such solutions:

```
FindInstance[ eq[x] == 0 && -5 < x < 5, {x, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5}, Integers, 5]
```

> ```
>  {{x -> -4, q1 -> 241, q2 -> 61715, q3 -> 13, q4 -> -6656, q5 -> 853412},
>   {x -> -1, q1 -> -103, q2 -> -103, q3 -> 38, q4 -> 3, q5 -> 38},
>   {x -> 3, q1 -> -39, q2 -> -3159, q3 -> -50, q4 -> 8153, q5 -> -328050},
>   {x -> -3, q1 -> 159, q2 -> 12879, q3 -> -50, q4 -> 8168, q5 -> -328050}, 
>   {x -> 2, q1 -> 113, q2 -> 1813, q3 -> -46, q4 -> 1516, q5 -> -11456}}
> ```

In case one prefers a general representation of solutions in terms of symbolic parameters we can proceed a different way. For the sake of simplicity at first we restrict our searching to the real domain. Suppressing conditional expressions with `Normal` and evaluating

```
x /. Solve[ eq[x] == 0, x, Reals] // Normal
```

we find  that all these solutions are simple root objects

```
Table[
  Root[ 4 q2^2 q5 - q5^2 + (4 q2^2 q4 - 8 q1 q2 q5) #1^4 + 
       (4 q2^2 q3 - 8 q1 q2 q4 + 4 q1^2 q5 + 2 q3 q5) #1^8 + 
       (-8 q1 q2 q3 + 4 q1^2 q4) #1^12 + (4 q1^2 q3 - q3^2) #1^16 &, k], {k, 8}] 
 == Normal[ x /. Solve[ eq[x] == 0, x, Reals]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

We can **represent these solutions in terms of radicals** (use `ToRadicals`), however formulae would be quite involved. 
On the other hand we can find simpler solutions assuming certain special conditions, one can observe that it would be reasonable to supplement `eq[x] == 0` with another equations expressing that two highest order coefficients (of `Root` expressions) vanish and then eliminating appropriate parameters from radicals, e.g.:

```
x /. Solve[ eq[x] == 0 && q3 == 4 q1^2 && -8 q1 q2 q3 + 4 q1^2 q4 == 0, 
            {x}, {q3, q4}] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Comment: congrats Artes, I didn't know that this is possible to do. But I think in any case big knowledge is necessary for this

Comment: @Pipe You should remember that the last output is a solution under these assumptions `q3 == 4 q1^2 && -8 q1 q2 q3 + 4 q1^2 q4 == 0`. If they are not satisfied you have to rely on `Solve` and `Reduce` which produce rather involved results in this case.